# Creating Polly retry policy creation for HTTP Transient exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, polly, retry-logic

I am trying to implement Polly retry for a method for HTTP transient exception but I am stuck.

```
CustomResponse response = getResponse(CustomRequest request)
```

`getResponse` has 2 implementations one using WCF another using API. These two implementation are in separate class.

If succeed I will get a response of my output type `CustomResponse`
Or it will throw exception such as serviceNotAvailable or Internal server error

I tried writing this below policy

```
Policy.handle<httpRequestException>()
    .Or<TimeOutexception()
    .Or<BadRequestException>()
```

But I am not able to get one for service not available and internal server error

Comment: Based on your description it seems like Service Not Available and Internal Server Error are status codes (not exceptions). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, atleast 500(Internal Server Error) are all the http status code

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is wire it up yourself. Here is an example with SQL and Win23 Errors, some errors such as Connection Failures I don't retry, others I return true in order to retry. Change this code to tap into the `HttpRequestException` in a similar way to this `SqlException` and `Win32Exception`:

```
.Handle<SqlException>(e => SqlHelper.ShouldRetryOn(e))
.Or<TimeoutException>()
.OrInner<Win32Exception>(Win32Helper.ShouldRetryOn)


public static bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception ex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new();
    if (ex is SqlException sqlException)
    {
        foreach (SqlError err in sqlException.Errors)
        {
            switch (err.Number)
            {




public static bool ShouldRetryOn(Win32Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex.NativeErrorCode)
    {
        // Timeout expired
        case 0x102:
            return true;
        // Semaphore timeout expired
        case 0x121:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively tap into Pollys  in built WaitAndRetry for Http calls `HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().WaitAndRetryAsync`

Comment: `HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().WaitAndRetryAsync` will not work on customOutput type dont know why
If you give me an example how to implement this, it would be really helpful

Comment: @User123 grab an example from github https://github.com/search?type=code&q=HandleTransientHttpError%28%29

Answer (score 0):

The `Handle` and `Or` builder methods help you to define trigger for exceptions.

The `HandleResult` and `OrResult` builder methods help you to define trigger based on the response/result object.

```
Policy
  .HandleResult<CustomResponse>(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServerInternalError)
  .Or<HttpRequestException>()
  .Or<TimeOutexception()
  .Or<BadRequestException>()
```

OR

```
Policy
  .Handle<HttpRequestException>() 
  .OrResult<CustomResponse>(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServerInternalError)
  .Or<TimeOutexception()
  .Or<BadRequestException>()
```

The above code samples assumed that the StatusCode is accessible through the `CustomResponse` object.

These samples can be easily extended to trigger for multiple statuscodes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response but with respect to CustomResponse, i do not have status code property, it only contains the data i get from getResponse method. which will have data only when call is success else it will be null.

Comment: @User123 If you don't have access to the status code then how do you want to define a policy which should trigger for specific status codes?